# Using sed to find-and-replace in a text file using strings from another text file

Tags: bash, sed

I have two files as follows. The first is `sample.txt`:

```
new haven co-op toronto on $1245
joe schmo co-op powell river bc $4444
```

The second is `locations.txt`:

```
toronto
powell river
on
bc
```

We'd like to use `sed` to produce a marked up `sample-new.txt` that added `;` before and after each of these. So that the final string would appear like:

```
new haven co-op ;toronto; ;on; $1245
joe schmo co-op ;powell river; ;bc; $4444
```

Is this possible using bash? The actual files are much longer (thousands of lines in each case) but as a one-time job we're not too concerned about processing time.

--- edited to add ---

My original approach was something like this:

`cat locations.txt | xargs -i sed 's/{}/;/' sample.txt`

But it only ran the script once per pattern, as opposed to the methods you've proposed here.

Comment: Please include your attempts to solve this [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35191776/edit). We can only help you with your code if we see your code.

Comment: @ghoti My early horrid approach added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete your set of options, you can do this in pure bash, slowly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t places < t2

while read line; do
  for place in "${places[@]}"; do
      line="${line/ $place / ;$place; }"
  done
  echo "$line"
done < t1
```

Note that this likely won't work as expected if you include places that are inside other places, for example "niagara on the lake" which is in "on":

```
foo bar co-op ;niagara ;on; the lake; on $1
```

Instead, you might want to do more targeted pattern matching, which will be much easier in awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Collect the location list into the index of an array
NR==FNR {
  places[$0]
  next
}

# Now step through the input file
{

  # Handle two-letter provinces
  if ($(NF-1) in places) {
      $(NF-1)=";" $(NF-1) ";"
  }

  # Step through the remaining places doing substitutions as we find matches
  for (place in places) {
    if (length(place)>2 && index($0,place)) {
      sub(place,";"place";")
    }
  }

}

# Print every line
1
```

This works for me using the data in your question:

```
$ cat places
toronto
powell river
niagara on the lake
on
bc
$ ./tst places input
new haven co-op ;toronto; ;on; $1245
joe schmo co-op ;powell river; ;bc; $4444
foo nar co-op ;niagara on the lake; ;on; $1
```

You may have a problem if your places file contains an actual non-province comprising two letters. I'm not sure if such things exist in Canada, but if they do, you'll either need to tweak such lines manually, or make the script more complex by handling provinces separately from cities.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next;} {for(i in a)gsub("\\<"a[i]"\\>",";"a[i]";"); print} '  locations.txt sample.txt
```

Using `awk+sed`

```
sed -f <(awk '{print "s|\\<"$0"\\>|;"$0";|g"}' locations.txt) sample.txt
```

Same using pure `sed`:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|\\<&\\>|\;&\;|g/' locations.txt) sample.txt
```

(After you show your coding attempts, I will add the explanation of why this works.)

Comment: Great stuff. The Awk-only solution is _GNU_-specific, due to use of `\<` and `\>`; Mawk and BSD Awk do not support these.
The Sed commands can be made to work with BSD Sed, which understands `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` in lieu of `\<` and `\>`, as follows:
`sed -f <(awk '{print "s|[[:<:]]"$0"[[:>:]]|;"$0";|g"}' locations.txt) sample.txt`
`sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|[[:<:]]&[[:>:]]|\;&\;|g/' locations.txt) sample.txt`

Comment: OK, I was searching for the word-break, like `\b`. Could not find it while posting the answer...

Comment: Unfortunately, support for word-boundary assertions is a mess, definitely across platforms, but even across the utility set of a given platform. I know of no word-boundary assertions that work in Mawk and BSD Awk. `\b` works in GNU Sed and GNU Grep (and even BSD Grep), but not in GNU Awk.

Comment: And, just to be clear: I think these are great solutions; I only wanted to point out the runtime environment constraints.

Comment: +1 for the warning about this being GNU awk specific. And as nice as these are, they fail if the location includes another location as a substring, as in "niagara on the lake". (I'm not sure if there are others.)

Comment: You could have just used `a[NR]=$0` instead of creating a new index variable `a[i++]=$0`.